# Variable in T-SQL

Tags: t-sql

I have the code T-SQL as follows:

```
declare @xml xml = N'
<a abb="122">
    <b>
    </b>
</a>
<a abb="344">
    <b>
    </b>
</a>';

declare @T table (XMLCol xml);

insert into @T values (@xml);

declare @sql varchar(max);
set @sql = 'update @T set
                     XMLCol.modify(''
                            replace value of (/a/@abb)[1] 
                            with 888'');';
exec (@sql);
```

When I execute, a fault segment appears:

```
Msg 1087, Level 15, State 2, Line 1
Must declare the table variable "@T".
```

How to declare variable @T to be understand?

Comment: Why can't this statement be static? I.e. what part is dynamic in it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a temp table instead of table variable.

```
declare @xml xml = N'
<a abb="122">
    <b>
    </b>
</a>
<a abb="344">
    <b>
    </b>
</a>';

create table #T (XMLCol xml);

insert into #T values (@xml);

declare @sql varchar(max);
set @sql = 'update #T set
                     XMLCol.modify(''
                            replace value of (/a/@abb)[1] 
                            with 888'');';
exec (@sql);

drop table #T
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use the EXEC statement or sp_executesql stored procedure to run a dynamic SQL Server query that refers a table variable, if the table variable was created outside the EXEC statement or sp_executesql stored procedure.

Use a temp table instead.

Answer (score 1):

Because you need to declare everything inside the dynamic part of the query.
In your case i still don´t understand why you need the dynamic query, but if it´s necesary it should look like:

```
declare @sql varchar(max);
set @sql = '
declare @xml xml = N''
<a abb="122">
    <b>
    </b>
</a>
<a abb="344">
    <b>
    </b>
</a>'';

declare @T table (XMLCol xml);
insert into @T values (@xml);
update @T set
                     XMLCol.modify(''
                            replace value of (/a/@abb)[1] 
                            with 888'');';
exec (@sql);
```

Answer (score 0):

Table variables are not seen in the inner SPs so you should define a temporary table there not a table variable.

Answer (score 0):

Because your @sql is executed on a different execution block so it will not find it. You need to declare your @t inside the "@sql" variable, including all transactions related to your @t.

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @xml xml = N'
<a abb="122">
    <b>
    </b>
</a>
<a abb="344">
    <b>
    </b>
</a>';

declare @T table (XMLCol xml);

insert into @T values (@xml);


select * from @t
update @T set XMLCol.modify('replace value of (/a/@abb)[1] with 888');
select * from @t
```

This will work for your result